# Why do not I have Qt Gui Application option?

Tags: qt, user-interface

As you can see from the picture it does not show Qt gui application option. What is that I am missing?

By the way it is Qt 5.2

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the *Qt Widgets Application* that you are looking for. All Qt GUI applications use Widgets.

Comment: Thank you. In the videos of Qt they always choose Qt Gui Application option. But appearently it was only in older versions.